# Search for image and get link

Tags: jquery, image, search

I am using the below code to search for images and then store there link in to a textarea.

But there is a problem that i don't know how to fix it. It's only work if i allow `alert` to display.

```
var links = '' , file = '' , img_exist = '';
$('a:has(img)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr('href').match(/(jpg)$/);
}).each(function(){
    file = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url:file,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function(){
            img_exist = false;
        },
        success: function(){
            img_exist = true;
        }
    });
    //alert('WTH?');
    if ( img_exist == true ){
        links = links + file + '\n';
    }
});
$('#sfi_link').val(links);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statement is executed right after the AJAX call is **sent** by the browser.
It does not wait for the response, since AJAX is **asynchronous**.

You will have to put `links = links + file + '\n';` in your `success` callback.

Comment: So, your AJAX call always fail? Have you tried debugging it, using web developer console in your favorite browser?

Comment: I am actually coding a user script, so i am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are using an async call as ajax request. 
the async callback happens after

```
if ( img_exist == true ){
        links = links + file + '\n';
}
```

so my advice to you is to put this code into the `success` function.